# Zingchart - Panning with Shift Key and MouseMove

Tags: javascript, charts, pan, zingchart

I want to implement a panning Option into my Zingchart. 
I want to pan throught the Graph when I move the Mouse while pressing the Shiftkey.
Can I achieve this with the Zingchart Json?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZingChart has traversal via scroll bars once a chart is zoomed in.

See : http://www.zingchart.com/docs/interactive-charts/chart-zoom-pan-scroll/#scrollbar-setup

Otherwise, ZingChart does not have panning in the traditional sense. You could emulate some sort of panning through the `zoomtovalues` API method which allows you to display values at a certain depth and range.

With that being said, we are in the process of developing a zoom/panning plugin for mobile users and should be out this quarter. I will look into extending panning for our desktop users. Feel free to sign up in our newsletter on our homepage to get updates on when this is released.

- ZingChart team member.